# Wifi won't connect after delete almost all package

Tags: wifi

Earlier I wanted to make Linux Ubuntu GUI to a CLI, after I changed my Linux to CLI. I removed all GUI related packages without further reading a depency that will delete (eg, X11).

However after I reboot, I find that my wifi can't connect to the internet or connected to router. I have tried restarting the wifi/Networkmanager, Even after reinstalling roughly what I deleted earlier, it still doesn't work.

**Changes:**

I've managed to fix it and get it working by running the command `sudo nmcli device up wlx8c18d9e25879`. But when rebooted, the wifi must be turned on manually using the command above, how do I make the wifi always turn on automatically when turned on?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Resolved]**

After try some experiment, I was able to solve this problem myself by running these command:

1. `nmcli device up "your wifi device"`
2. `nmcli device reapply "your wifi device"`
3. Check the wifi by run `nmcli`

Example:

1. `nmcli device up wlx8c18d9e25879`
2. `nmcli device reapply wlx8c18d9e25879`
3. `nmcli`

[image: Succes fixed]